# Access front-end with back-end permissions

Tags: mysql, ms-access, permissions, mariadb

I have a MariaDB database that uses LDAP authentication so that database accounts are tied to their windows ones. If I develop a MS Access front-end, will their enterprise login be enough to restrict access to certain tables? Will I need to develop several front-ends or will they just get an error when they try to edit a linked table they are not supposed to?

Comment: I guess if users just try to add or edit information in a table displayed in Access then they will see an error and that's it. But if you use Access with forms and VBA then you should know if the current user has read/write access to certain tables. Otherwise you will have to handle lots of possible errors in your code.